# HTML 5 draggable attributes with React

Tags: reactjs

Is there any problem with using HTML5 dragable attributes inside a react app? 
Will those attributes create conflicts with react DOM and actual DOM?

```
render() {
var listItems = this.state.colors.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <li 
      data-id={i}
      key={i}
      draggable='true'
      onDragEnd={this.dragEnd.bind(this)}
      onDragStart={this.dragStart.bind(this)}>{item}</li>
  )
 });
    return (
        <ul onDragOver={this.dragOver.bind(this)}>
    {listItems}
  </ul>
    )
}
```

Can anyone give an advise me on this. I am trying to create dragable element list on react. Any recommended way to create it in react or do I need to use a react library like React DnD?